# Prove language is not Turing-recognizable using contradiction

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Show that the language L = {<M>| M is a TM and does not accept <M>} is not Turing-recognizable.

Note: Prove by contradiction. No need for reduction.

This is the problem I am trying to solve. I'm confused on how to do this without using reduction.

Comment: Suppose that some machine $A$ recognizes $L$. Can you determine whether or not $\langle A\rangle$ is in $L$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that the language $L$ is decidable, so then exists a Turing Machine $M'$ such that $M'$ stops for all inputs (doesn't loop infinitely) and that $L(M') = L $.

If $\omega$ is the codification for $M'$, What happens with $M'$ with input $\omega$?

$M$' accepts $\omega$, if and only if, (as $\omega$ encodes $M'$), $M'$ does not accept $M'$, a contradiction.

This is the same idea to prove undecidability of the Halting problem and numerous other results, the idea of diagonalization